# Remove commas by using display format in c#

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Ex:
DataType Int
int value =1,088
I want like this 1088 without comma by using DataAnnotations In  c# MVC.

Sample Format to Understood the this.
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")] public decimal? CurrentNumberOfHoldings { get; set; }`

Comment: Is "," the 1000-Separator or the decimal? If the former, then "N0" won't work.

Comment: A [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) is probably needed here. It may be as simple as `{0:0}` - see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfSnwc)